# How can I avoid breaking a promise chain when using q.map?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I think I may have gotten too fancy with promises. I have an array of geese, and there's an arbitrary number of operations I would like to perform before returning a final value. I've found that after the first return statement, the chain is broken. If my collection has 10 items, exactly 10 items will be placed in the database, but I get null values when I try to build my API response from the "return Q.all(promises)" statement below.

To test, I've put a console.log statement inside a promise that fires after the first one and a console.log inside of my expressjs route which is expecting details on geese. The API response always finishes first "[null, null]" and then eventually I get entries for my 2nd and 3rd promises in the chain.

How did I create this race condition and how can I fix it?

```
var promises = geese.map(function(goose) {
 determineGooseType(goose.details)
  .then(function(type) {
    return recordNewGooseType(type)
  })
  .then(function(dbInsertResult) {
    we never really got here!
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
   log some stuff
  });
}

return Q.all(promises);
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic but your first callback can be shortened to `.then(recordNewGooseType)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array of promises, you have an array of `undefined` values (and `Q.all` didn't warn you about it): Your mapper function is not returning anything. You're missing a `return` statement there:

```
var promises = geese.map(function(goose) {
  return determineGooseType(goose.details)
//^^^^^^
  .then(function(type) {
    return recordNewGooseType(type)
  })
  .then(function(dbInsertResult) {
    // now getting here before resolving the .all() promise!
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
   log some stuff
  });
}
return Q.all(promises);
```

Comment: He said he never gets to the second then inside the chain - while the return is indeed missing this can't be the (only) issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I wasn't sure, but I interpreted "*The API response always finishes* first *"[null, null]" and then* eventually *I get entries for my 2nd and 3rd promises in the chain*" as that "never" is inaccurate, he only has "wrong" timing of his log statements. If there are other problems left after fixing the `return`, he should have a look at your answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This means there are two options:

Either `recordNewGooseType` is promisified incorrectly or `determineGooseType` is. Specifically - since you said the API response `determineGooseType` returns `[null, null]` the only reasonable assumption is that `recordNewGooseType` is to blame.

This means that the promisified `recordNewGooseType` is not calling `resolve`.

You can verify this by running it on a single goose rather than 10 geese.